# log4net elasticsearch logging with custom parameters

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, log4net

I am using log4net together with ElasticSearch and Kibana.
By now my web.config looks like this:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="ElasticSearchAppender" type="log4net.ElasticSearch.ElasticSearchAppender, log4net.ElasticSearch">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date - %level - %message %property{location} %property{label} %property{mstimeload} %property{applicationid} %property{page} 
           %property{ipclient} %property{browser} %property{browsersignature} %property{appversion} %property{sessionuniquecodetag} %property{globalcountertailsloaded} 
           %property{ipserveraddress} %newline" />
  </layout>
  <connectionString value="Server=myip;Index=logstash;Port=9200;rolling=true"/>
  <lossy value="true" />
  <bufferSize value="100" />
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="ERROR"/>
  </evaluator>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="ElasticSearchAppender" />
</root>
```

I have some custom parameters like location, label, mstimeload, applicationid, page, ipclient, ...
Everything works fine, but all of these parameters are of `string` type, instead I would like to have also `integer` or `geo_point` type, but I don't know how to tell log4net of which type is my parameter.
Then in c# I write my log like this:

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["label"] = label;
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["ipclient"] = ipaddress;
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["browser"] = browserType;
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["browsersignature"] = browserHashSignature;
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["appversion"] = ASSettings.ApplicationVersion;
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["mstimeload"] = msTime == null ? null : Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(msTime.Value), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["globalcountertailsloaded"] = globalCounter_tilesloaded == null ? null : Convert.ToString(globalCounter_tilesloaded.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["ipserveraddress"] = ipserveraddress;
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["page"] = page;
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["sessionuniquecodetag"] = sessionuniquecodetag;
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["applicationid"] = applicationid;
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["location"] = ASSecurity.GetLatLongFromIp(ipaddress);

log.Error(description, ex);
```

But I am not sure if this is the best way to do it or if there are also other ways.

Comment: As you're putting all these properties into one big string, what's the point of using any other types?

Comment: I am not putting all the properties in one big string.. each of these property is separate and is in fact a "column" in kibana. I can search through them. I would like to have another of these property but not of the string type and if I do in this way like i did by now, the properties are of string type. I would like to know how to add a property of another specific type.

Comment: have you tried to configure a template for your index? it might do the work